# How to select data from Basic authorization with post data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

How to select some data from this service (http://192.168.1.18/service/test) which this value > {"number":"11224455", "name":"person1"}
. Basic authorization: {username: "admin",password: "pass123"}

This is the sample of making a POST request in C# with Basic Authentication: It goes error with: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. where put I username and password?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://192.168.1.18/service/test");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close ();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: How do I select data with value {"number":"11224455", "name":"person1"}?

Comment: And should add this line to pass basic authorization:           `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin1", "pass123");`

Answer (score 1):

Since your comment seems to suggest it's a single resulting JSON object:

Declare your class with the properties you need to capture:

```
public class Person
{

    public int number { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can capture it via Newtonsoft.Json with something like this:

```
        Person person = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(responseFromServer);
        Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, name: {1}", person.name, person.number);
```

Comment: where can I put Basic authorization username and password?

Comment: You'll need to import the reference for Newtonsoft JSON for it to work.

Comment: It goes error with The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. How to put username and password it?

Comment: That all depends on how the post username/pass are handled.  What are you trying to accomplish?   Also, what do you mean by "basic auth"  a Username/pass popup when you head to that page?

Comment: I just got username and password actually I dont know what they are handled I have just this information: `{username: "admin",password: "pass123"}`
I tried to browse it directly then it didn't ask username pass popup.
I think it has to something like this: `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "pass123");`